# Loop never seems to actually loop

Tags: python

```
print("Welcome to my dice game.")
print("First enter how many sides you would like your dice to have, 4, 6 or 12")
print("Then this program will randomly roll the dice and show a number")
#Introduction explaing what the game will do. Test 1 to see if it worked.
while True:
    #starts a while loop so the user can roll the dice as many times as they find necessary
    import random
    #Imports the random function so the code will be able to randomly select a number
    dice = int(input("Enter which dice you would to use,4, 6, or 12? "))
    #set a variable for the amount of dice number
    if dice == 12:
        x = random.randint(1,12)
        print("You picked a 12 sided dice. You rolled a " + str(x) + " well done")
        #Test 2 see if it does pick a random number for a 12 sided di
    elif dice == 6:
        x = random.randint(1,6)
        print("You picked a 6 sided dice. You rolled a " + str(x) + " well done")
        #Test 3 see if it does pick a random number for a 6 sided di
    elif dice == 4:
        x = random.randint(1,4)
        print("You picked a 4 sided dice. You rolled a " + str(x) + " well done")
        #Test 4 see if it does pick a random number for a 4 sided di
    else:
        print("Sorry, pick either 12, 6 or 4")
        #Test 5 tells the user that they can only pick 4, 6 or 12 if anything else is entered this error shows
    rollAgain = input ("Roll Again? ")
    if rollAgain == "no":
            rollAgain = False
    if rollAgain == "yes":
        rollAgain = True
        break
print ("Thank you for playing")
#if the user enters anything apart from yes y or Yes. The code ends here.
```

That is the code i have so far. However the code will never actually go to the beginning of the loop, no matter what i enter the code just displays "Thanks for playing" and ends. Can anyone please tell me where i have went wrong?

Comment: This formatting is hurting my eyes.. and my feelings.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: looks like you break the loop if the user selects "yes" to roll again.  This looks reversed.

Comment: Double-spacing is for term papers, not source code.

Comment: You could also eliminate the break and change your while loop to `while rollAgain is True`.  Although just adding the break to the `rollAgain=="no"` would fix it I think.

Comment: If you're using Python 2.x, you want `raw_input()`, not `input()`. This set aside, this code "works" for me (meaning : it gets into the while loop - there are quite a few bugs).

Comment: Conventionally, line comments go before the code they comment on.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should be using raw_input to get the user's selection. (assuming python 2) If you're using python 3 then input is fine and keep reading.

Anyway, it'll still quit when you type yes because you break out of the loop! You should move the break statement into the "no" case so it breaks out when you say you do not want to roll again.

```
rollAgain = raw_input ("Roll Again? ")
if rollAgain == "no":
    break
```

You don't need to set rollAgain to true or false at all. With the above code, anything other than "no" is assumed to be "yes" but you can add checks for that easily.

Comment: For what it's worth, if you define `rollAgain` as `True` before your while loop, you can do `while rollAgain:` instead of `while True`, and then do `if input("Would you like to roll again? ").lower().startswith('n'): rollAgain = False`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you break your loop when the user wants to roll the dice again. The loop should break when the player doesn't want to play again so you have to do :

http://pastebin.com/hzC1UwDM

Comment: FYI it's not a good idea to use pastebin or other websites to host code on SO. Learn to use the [editor](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and put the code in your answer. Also, you only need the parts that you modified, not the whole thing. Makes it easier to see what's different.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. You are right, I will try to conform accordingly.